# Automatic domain mapping with SSL

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, devops

I have built a platform where users can register and write blogs. When they register, a subdomain is created automatically.

For eg. the domain is `https://example.com` and if they register with `foo`, then their dedicated site would be `https://foo.example.com`. This works as expected.

I want to extend this functionality with custom domain mapping, where a user with a domain should be able to map with my hosting server. And below is the direction, it should work.

- Get the domain from user. eg. `foo.com`
- Create a nginx config with the reverse proxy programmatically.
- Reload nginx.
- Ask the user to create an `A` record with the server ip address.

While this can work, I don't know how to handle SSL certificate. While creating the nginx config, I should be creating that certificate, but it needs domain verification. How can this process work ? What is the correct automated way of doing this ?

Comment: You either ask the user for SSL certificate or you need to use LetsEncrypt

Comment: If I use LetsEncrypt, there is a verification step. LetsEncrypt will not proceed untill thats done. I don't know to keep the LetsEncrupt process active untill the verification is done.

Comment: As Tarun sayd, use letsencrypt. Tell the user to point the A record in his domain to your service. Then create via letsencrypt the certifcates and as last step, create the nginx config. If the custom domain points with the A record towards your service, you can create a SSL certificate with the HTTP challange: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS cloud you can use an ELB and generate custom SSL cert for custom domain and add it to ELB listner. You can use the AWS APIs or cli to  automate this process